what exactly does the fs.quota.syncs sysctl parameter in Linux do?
We are debugging high load/low CPU issues that ultimately crash the system on a customers SLES 8.8 VMs.
I compared the sysctl values and noticed the instances on which the problem occurred the issues both had significantly lower values (3 digits vs. 4-5 digits) for fs.quota.syncs than other VMs that did not have those issues.
Maybe it's a red herring but I am still trying to understand what this parameter actually does, why it's different on each VM and if it could have something to do with the problems we're seeing. It seems to be badly documented though, as my Google-fu did not help me

The fs.quota.syncs sysctl is a read-only counter; it exposes the value of the DQST_SYNCS filesystem quota statistic. The sysctl is defined in  fs/quota/dquot.c:
static struct ctl_table fs_dqstats_table[] = {
  // ...
    {
        .procname   = "syncs",
        .data       = &dqstats.stat[DQST_SYNCS],
        .maxlen     = sizeof(unsigned long),
        .mode       = 0444,
        .proc_handler   = do_proc_dqstats,
    },
  // ...
};

It is incremented whenever dquot_writeback_dquots is called:
/* Write all dquot structures to quota files */
int dquot_writeback_dquots(struct super_block *sb, int type)
{
  // ...

    dqstats_inc(DQST_SYNCS);

    // ...
}

So this is effectively, "how many times have we synchronized quota data to disk".

Note that in older versions of the kernel (2.6.32 or earlier), this counter was incremented in vfs_quota_sync.

thanks! I appreciate the detailed reply.
This makes a lot of sense since these machines where recently restarted, so naturally the counter is low. red herring after all. Still very helpful reply, thanks again.
